# add password protection or prompt to certain bash commands

Tags: command-line, sudo, rclone

sorry if this has already been asked but i cant find an answer

today I accidentally deleted a lot of sensitive work-related data cause i was absent minded... instead of typing "rclone ls s3-W54689000078:all_data" I typed "rclone delete s3-W54689000078:all_data"
Its a miracle that i didnt lose anything important and mainly cause i saw what i typed immediately but i would like to add an extra layer of security to the "rclone delete" command.
Is there any way that i can either make it a sudo command or simply make the terminal prompt me when i type rclone delete?

cheers

Comment: Just as an option. Remove write permission for the user you are working on from folder where sensitive and important files are stored. Only admin/root should have write access to these folders. So, for cases you need to change something in such folders you will need to use `sudo`. And configure regular automatic backup for these folders.

Comment: You could replace the `rclone` command with a script that will check for the `delete`
parameter and will prompt for confirmation, using `alias` for `rclone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As fast response, I have an idea,
you can write the following bash script:

```sh
echo "Are you sure? (Yes/No)"
read result;
if [[ "$result" == "Yes"  ]]; then
        exit 0
else
        exit 1
fi
```

then use `chmod` to give executable access

```
$ chmod a+x confirm.sh
```

and use `alias` to protect some command, for example:

```
$ alias rclone_delete="~/confirm.sh && rclone delete"
```

You can improve confirm script for your use case, such as change the question to "Enter password" and change "Yes" to a specific password